# Car wont turn over after trying to get it out of snow

Tags: engine, fuel-system, fuel-injection

I have a 1998 Mustang V6. Last winter I attempted to get it out of the snow on an inclined driveway. I revved it apparently too hard and the engine sputtered for a moment and stopped. Since then it has not turned over. I get a good crank but it just doesn't seem to want to turn over. I have looked up some possible answers online and was directed to a possible "Emergency" fuel line switch that may have popped when i pushed the car over the limits but I can't seem to find it (if it even exists). Any suggestions?

Comment: When you say "turn over" do you mean it will crank but will not start? Or do you mean the engine does nothing, but you can hear the clank of the starter as it hits the flywheel? When a person says "I turned the engine over", that indicates to me they have turned the key to the start position and the engine is cranking away (being caused to rotate internally). Can you explain *exactly* what you mean here?

Comment: When I turn the key, I get a cranking sound. Meaning the engine is attempting to start but will not get to the point of turning over and starting the engine itself.

Comment: You need to start looking at the basics, then ... Is it getting fuel (pressure gauge on the Schrader valve); Does it have spark (Check ignition source at spark plug), etc. Have you checked any of these things to ensure you don't have an obvious issue?

Answer (score 3):

Your post raises several possible issues that you could eliminate to start with.

Firstly if it is still on an incline I suggest you push or tow it to flat ground. It will help rule out fuel starvation and make it easier and safer to work on.

Second i would drain the fuel tank and put fresh fuel in it.

From there you can try starting it a few times. Give it a few minutes break between attempts so you don't drain the battery, fry the starter or flood the engine.

You could also try some aerosol engine start products. Beyond this point you're looking at removing/cleaning/checking/ replacing spark plugs. Looking for spark etc.

Is it a manual transmission or auto? Not sure how confident you are with the technique, but if it's a manual you could try tow starting it.  Note: if you are not familiar with this then i suggest you don't attempt this.

Answer (score 0):

Typically the fuel injection cut off switch is located under the front passenger seat but on your specific car it appears to be located in the drivers side of the trunk behind an access panel.

More vehicle specific information [here](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20121130055352AAEw0yV)

Comment: Upon looking at that switch, it appears that it is depressed, so I am guessing that it has not been tripped.